# Help with boxes with equations and their respective explanations with another color

Tags: boxes, tikz-arrows

hoping you are excellent, I would like to ask your help to know how to generate the following graphic, an apology if the text shown is in Spanish, but if I would like to know how to generate that type of box that also indicates the step where it is changed sign the terms. The translation of the text would be "The sign must be changed when a term is passed from one side of the '=' sign to the other". I appreciate your time and help too much.

[image]

Comment: No bad intention here, but, as a math teacher, I would strongly discourage anyone to use this kind of explanation. This could lead to misunderstanding and confusion in the long run. A better way is to use equivalent algebraic operations on both sides, i.e. substract 8 here. As for the way to implement the arrow you want, you sure could find a solution with some research here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One very inelegant way to do this, if it's on a short term is the following.

```
\documentclass[border=1pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={inner ysep=1pt}]

    \tikzstyle{operation}=[->,>=latex]
    \tikzstyle{sqr}=[midway,fill=black!20]
    
    \node (EQ1)   {\strut $=$};
    \node[left=5pt] (A1) at (EQ1) {\strut $2x+8$};
    \node[right=5pt] (B1) at (EQ1) {\strut $14$};
    
    \node[below of=EQ1] (EQ2) {\strut $=$};
    \node[left=5pt] (A2) at (EQ2) {\strut $2x$};
    \node[right=5pt] (B2) at (EQ2) {\strut $14-8$};
    
    \draw[->] (A1.-35) --++ (0,-6pt) -| (B2.35);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

You may want to learn how to `remember picture` in TiKz, in order to do a better version of this, especially if you want to decorate more both the +8 and the -8.

[image: Arrow between equations]

Comment: Nice and clean explanation (+1). Use of the `\tikzstyle` is deprecated. Instead it is intend `\tikzset` or define stale as options of `tikzpicture`: `\begin{tikzpicture}[
every node/.style = {inner ysep=1pt},
 operation/.style = {->,>=latex},
       sqr/.style = {midway,fill=black!20}
                    ]`

Comment: Yes, you're right, I just forgot to delete those two lines which are useless here. I'll edit them.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more elegant solution, using `overlay` and `remember picture`, as I suggested before.
This way, you may first write your several equations in the `align*` environment, then replace some bits with `tikz` nodes. Finally, you just have to draw between those nodes (this is what `overlay` is meant to do).

*edit: note that you have to compile twice in order to draw correctly the arrow, since LaTeX has to compute the node positions first, then draw between them.*

[image: Version 3]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{every picture/.style={remember picture}}
\tikzset{hilite/.style={anchor=base,rectangle,rounded corners,fill=orange,inner xsep=1pt}}
\tikzset{my arrow/.style={orange,rounded corners,line width=1pt,->}}

\begin{align*}
    2x\,\tikz[baseline]{
            \node[hilite] (plus8)
            {$+\,8$}} &= 14\\
            \\
    2x &= 14\, \tikz[baseline]{
            \node[hilite] (minus8)
            {$-\,8$}}
\end{align*}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
    \draw[my arrow] (plus8.south) --++ (0,-9pt) -| (minus8.north);
\end{tikzpicture}

         
\end{document}
```